# How to make XCode 4 build and run code automatically when changes are saved?

Tags: c++, xcode, tdd

I am using XCode for test driven development in C++.

It occurred to me that I would save a lot of time if XCode could automatically build and run my tests every time I save.

Is there any way to do this (by scripting XCode or otherwise)? Google doesn't seem to have a clue.

I have seen this workflow when using interpreted languages and it really does increase productivity.

Let's assume that my machine is fast enough to build and run tests in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

automatically? no. you could write your own fsevent monitor agent. when a change occurs that requires a rebuild, do something appropriate.

the easy way around this: you can configure xcode to save when building. you don't need save explicitly, just hit run with this preference enabled. in that sense, hitting run is as simple as hitting save, and that performs a save, build and run in the correct order when you hit run. You may want an intermediate target or scheme for this.

another option would be to use a vc commit as a trigger for a build and run of your tests (saw your comment: use branches).

Comment: Perfect! Can't believe I didn't think of this :) I just hit Apple+R instead of Apple+S and it's sweet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting C++, then you're probably out of luck.

With Objective-C, there's a project called «Injection»:
http://injectionforxcode.com/

It tracks the changes to your project files, and when a change occurs, it re-build the files as categories, placed inside a bundle.

The bundle is then loaded dynamically into the running app, and the contents from the categories replace the running code.

But it's Objective-C. C++ does not have such a runtime and capabilities.
Anyway, you may want to take a look at it... : )

Comment: Can you please guide how to use injectionforxcode plugin with xcode 4.6.1 and iOS 6.1. I have tried using it... A bit successful also. But not exactly what it says and demonstrate. I was trying this using UICatalog code from Apple and I found that when I change ButtonViewController before i navigate to that screen, then Changes are reflected **BUT** If i have already navigated to ButtonViewController then changes are **NOT** Reflected.

Comment: So how to reload controller? Because when I go back from Button to TableViewController and change the Button code, then also it is not getting reflected. Code injection works only for First time before page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think this can be done.

Most projects don't build and test in the fraction of a second it would require for it to be practical to do on every save anyway (i.e., whenever Xcode autosaves).

A lot of work has gone into the infrastructure for just getting Xcode's live errors and warnings. As long as your project isn't too weird those live errors ought to give a pretty good proxy for actually building it anyway.

For testing you might want to look into continuous integration if you don't already use it.

---

Grey-beards that grew up before autosave may have developed the habit of occasionally using a key command to save manually. Such users may be able to change that habit by substituting the key command that runs the tests for the key command they use to manually save.

Comment: Continuous integration comes into the picture only after you have committed code to source control. The workflow I'm talking about comes even before committing to source control. 

Build warnings and errors just aren't a good enough substitute.